# Proving the inequality $e^{\sin(\sqrt{2}/{7})}<11/9$ without calculator

Tags: inequality

Proving the inequality

> $$e^{\sin(\sqrt{2}/{7})}<11/9$$ without calculator

I tried to prove it by taking some terms of Taylor series to find a value which comparison with the $11/9$ but I countered the following problem:

"How can I use the $\sqrt{2}$ without calculator especially with the odd power"

Comment: [Oh, boy...](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19188)

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Is it some contest problem or were you just playing around with a calculator?

Comment: Put x= 0.02 in the expansion of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} $ to get a good approximation for $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: $11/9 - e^{\sin (\sqrt{2}/7)} = 0.00001435084425...$ So if you came up with it yourself, and need a proof, don't get your hopes up. While there might be a nice proof, it is unlikely to be found...

Answer (score 6):

The inequality is equivalent to
$$
\sin\frac{\sqrt2}{7}<\log\frac{11}{9}.
$$
We use the facts that the taylor series for $\sin x$ and $\log(1+x)$ are alternating and their terms are decreasing in absolute value.

First step: bound $\sin(\sqrt2/7)$ from above.
$$
\sin\frac{\sqrt2}{7}<\frac{\sqrt2}{7}-\frac{1}{3!}\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt2}{7}\Bigr)^3+\frac{1}{5!}\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt2}{7}\Bigr)^5=\sqrt2\,\frac{23847}{168070}<\frac{99}{70}\,\frac{23847}{168070}<0.20067
$$

Second step: bound $\log(11/9)$ from below.
$$
\log\Bigl(1+\frac29\Bigr)>\sum_{n=1}^8\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\Bigl(\frac29\Bigr)^n=\frac{302337356}{1506635235}>0.20067
$$
I used Mathematica to do the computations, but they can be done by hand in a reasonable time.

Comment: how you know the $\sqrt{2}<99/70$??

Comment: @Ehegh Why don't you square it?

Comment: ok, you are right

Comment: $$2=\frac{100}{50}<\frac{100}{49}=\Bigl(\frac{10}{7}\Bigr)^2.$$ This is not good enough to obtain the desired inequality. So I checked $99/70$ and $98/70$.